# JSON Output using Jackson and PrintWriter

Tags: javascript, java, json, jackson, printwriter

I simply used this for my writer

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

Then my Jackson generates the JSON, I have to go over the data in a ajax so I wanted to have it as JSON not as String

For a String:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ToJson obj = new ToJson();
        String obj1 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        out.append(obj1);
        out.close();
```

Which leaves me with `{"prname1":"P1neu","anz1":"1","prid1":"1","price1":"25"}` and I cant acces it with obj.prname1/etc

So I was trying this:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ToJson obj = new ToJson();
        String obj1 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        objectMapper.writeValue(out, obj1);
        System.out.println(obj);
        out.close();
```

But it leaves me with this: `ShoppingCart$1ToJson@4974cd9e`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is, converting the object (i.e. `obj`) to JSON string (i.e. `obj1`) and then writing the `obj1` which is a `String` instead of the `obj` which is the actual `Object` you need.

So, try replacing

```
String obj1 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
objectMapper.writeValue(out, obj1);
```

with

```
objectMapper.writeValue(out, obj);
```

---

Comment: I think I made a typo or I missunderstand you. obj produces ShoppingCart$1ToJson@3ea224a8 and obj1 the string which I cant access. What am I supposed to do with the cryptic obj value?

Answer (score 0):

to fit the requirements you had mention the code below should work.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Cart cart = new Cart("name", 1, 2.0F);
ObjectWriter pr = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
PrintWriter error = new PrintWriter(System.err); //use this if you want to send errors to a different output

try {
    String output = pr.forType(Cart.class).writeValueAsString(cart);
    pw.print(output);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    pw.print("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    pw.flush();
}
```

i used the this simple model

```
public class Cart {
    public String name;
    public int count;
    public float price;
}
```

on the javascript side you need to pass the inbound string to `JSON.parse()`

so for example

```
$.ajax({}).then((txt) => {
   //if you didn't tell the javascript library to handle the json parsing then 
  var json = JSON.parser(txt);
  console.log(json.name); //should print "name"
});
```